# Can't read response from XML-RPC

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, xml-rpc

I'm currently using XML-RPC from http://www.xml-rpc.net/

I've seen hundred of examples getting one result from the service and storing it in a struct, but I need to store "N" values.

I'll explain it better. I have a source file containing, basically this:

```
public struct estructura
{
    public string apiKey;
}

[XmlRpcUrl("http://example.net/api/xmlrpc/thisfile.php")]

public interface IStateName : IXmlRpcProxy
{
    [XmlRpcMethod("myserver.search.getSomething")]
    XmlRpcStruct busqueda(estructura co);
}
```

I've also one aspx file with this on PageLoad

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IStateName proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IStateName>();

    try
    {
        estructura uno;
        uno.apiKey = "My_API_Key_Value"; // Hidden for security reasons
        XmlRpcStruct a = proxy.busqueda(uno);               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Some error...");
    }

}
```

This actually works, I'm using Fiddler to read HTTP Requests/Responses and all is fine, the service returns this...

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 01 Feb 2011 16:06:51 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.1.6
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: close
XMLRPC-server: SimpleXMLRPC/0.7
Content-Length: 2177
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8


<methodResponse>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <struct>
                    <member>
                        <name>ATEId</name>

                        <value>
                        <string>6</string>
                        </value>
                    </member>

                    <member>
                    <name>ATEDescripcionEsp</name>

                    <value>
                    <string>* No Especificado *</string>
                    </value>
                    </member>
                </struct>
            </value>
        </param>

        <param>
            <value>
                <struct>
                    <member>
                        <name>ATEId</name>

                        <value>
                        <string>10</string>
                        </value>
                    </member>

                    <member>
                        <name>ATEDescripcionEsp</name>

                        <value>
                        <string>Asociaciones de empresas</string>
                        </value>
                    </member>
                </struct>
            </value>
        </param>

        <param>
        [The rest of params...]
        </param>
    </params>
</methodResponse>
```

My problem is that "var a" stores ONLY the first "param", I mean, I debugged the code and "a" contains only these entries

```
Name                        Value
["ATEDescripcionEsp"]   "* No Especificado *"   
["ATEId"]                   "6"
```

So I only want to store ALL results (next result should be ATEId=10 and ATEDescripcionEsp="Asociaciones de Empresas") from the server response or, If I can't do that, I need to store the plain XML from the response, then I would parse it manually.

Comment: Please don't put things like "c#" in the title. That's what we have tags for.

Answer (score 0):

It  looks like you are returning a set of values. You may want to consider changing the schema of the structure to accept an array or make the struct an array of values.

Comment: Ok, I forgot to tell, I can't change the service, it's sealed, I didn't make it, I can't change it.

Comment: Your C# code needs to parse the XML as an array. You shouldn't need to change the PHP service.